# Can I use Paragon assets store assets in other Engines besides Unreal?

Tags: assets, unreal, copyright

Epic Games recently [released a lot of assets from their game Paragon for free](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/assets?lang=&q=Paragon). I like some of them but am not particularly fond of the Unreal Engine.

Can I use those assets in another engine like Unity or something custom?

Comment: Please check that I fixed the names right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have read the description on the assets

> Licensed for use only with UE4 based products. Includes the character model, animations and skins

Other assets that Unreal didn't make themselves are fine to use in other engines as far I have found. If you want to be sure read the description and the license that comes with the asset.

Comment: not really free are we epik gamez?